# angular.module is not function in webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am beginner for learn angular and webpack, I using node command prompt to run angular in webpack, I am just given angular.min.js link in app.js file but the bundle.js not accept the anguar.module(), it is says angular.module is not a function, please help me to achieve this

```
var angular = require('../node_modules/angular/angular.js');
var ngModule = angular.module('app',[]);
console.log(ngModule);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebPack will load modules directly from `node_modules` without having to be configured to do so. You just need to add them as entry points in the config.

**webpack.config.js**

```
entry: {
    vendor: ['angular'],
    app: './src/app.js'
}
```

You can add other modules like `lodash` or `jquery` this way as well.

Now in your code you can use `angular` like this

```
import angular from 'angular';

export default angular.module('app',[]);
```

You can then import the module in other JS files like this.

```
import app from './app.js';

app.directive('myWidget',.....);
```

Comment: sorry sir, I am using angular 1.6.4, if any another way to run the project please tell me sir

Comment: I Get this error sir:  ERROR in chunk app [entry]
bundle.js
Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename bundle.js